# CLLocationManager enabled but checked Never

Tags: swift, authorization, cllocationmanager, appdelegate, cllocation

I am trying to determine in AppDelegate if user set location permissions for application to "Never". My app always crashing if not getting location.

my code in AppDelegate is:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    //location
    var manager = CLLocationManager()       
    if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .Restricted
            || .authorizationStatus() == .Denied {
        manager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: it's simply crashing with nil

Comment: Is this Xcode 6 or 7?

Comment: Once I fixed the obvious compile errors, the code you posted does not crash. It also doesn't make a whole lot of sense. If authorizationStatus is Restricted, then the user *can't* grant access and if the status is Denied then the user has already denied status. Asking for authorization in either case is useless.

Comment: @Anton, Whether CLLocationManager that you used in rootviewcontroller of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best article about CoreLocation and requesting authorization is here: http://nshipster.com/core-location-in-ios-8/

A couple of points:

1. Only request authorization if the current status is .NotDetermined
2. If the current status is .Denied, then you can post an alert asking
   the user to go into settings and turn on location services, but calling either of the request methods will do nothing.
3. Remember to put in a NSLocationUsageDescription in your plist! (I
   forget this routinely.)